# How do change from Google App Engine from Flexible Environment to Standard environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-app-engine, gcloud

I'm trying to migrate from a flexible environment to a standard environment. I made the mistake of having having `env: flex` in my app.yaml on the first deployment. When I deploy with `env: standard` I get the confirmation `Deployed service [default] to [project]`, though the deployment seems way too fast to be true. When I request the app I get a 500 error. I'm using ruby on rails.

```
2020-09-22 03:11:12 default[20200921t205538]  Puma starting in single mode...
2020-09-22 03:11:12 default[20200921t205538]  * Version 4.3.3 (ruby 2.7.1-p83), codename: Mysterious Traveller
2020-09-22 03:11:12 default[20200921t205538]  * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
2020-09-22 03:11:12 default[20200921t205538]  * Environment: production
2020-09-22 03:11:12 default[20200921t205538]  * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:8081
2020-09-22 03:11:12 default[20200921t205538]  bundler: failed to load command: rackup (/workspace/.bundle/gems/ruby/2.7.0/bin/rackup)
2020-09-22 03:11:12 default[20200921t205538]  Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - tmp/pids/server.pid
2020-09-22 03:11:12 default[20200921t205538]    /layers/google.ruby.bundle/gems/.bundle/gems/ruby/2.7.0/gems/puma-4.3.3/lib/puma/launcher.rb:216:in `initialize'
2020-09-22 03:11:12 default[20200921t205538]    /layers/google.ruby.bundle/gems/.bundle/gems/ruby/2.7.0/gems/puma-4.3.3/lib/puma/launcher.rb:216:in `open'
2020-09-22 03:11:12 default[20200921t205538]    /layers/google.ruby.bundle/gems/.bundle/gems/ruby/2.7.0/gems/puma-4.3.3/lib/puma/launcher.rb:216:in `write_pid'
2020-09-22 03:11:12 default[20200921t205538]    /layers/google.ruby.bundle/gems/.bundle/gems/ruby/2.7.0/gems/puma-4.3.3/lib/puma/launcher.rb:105:in `write_state'
2020-09-22 03:11:12 default[20200921t205538]    /layers/google.ruby.bundle/gems/.bundle/gems/ruby/2.7.0/gems/puma-4.3.3/lib/puma/single.rb:103:in `run'
2020-09-22 03:11:12 default[20200921t205538]    /layers/google.ruby.bundle/gems/.bundle/gems/ruby/2.7.0/gems/puma-4.3.3/lib/puma/launcher.rb:172:in `run'
2020-09-22 03:11:12 default[20200921t205538]    /layers/google.ruby.bundle/gems/.bundle/gems/ruby/2.7.0/gems/puma-4.3.3/lib/rack/handler/puma.rb:73:in `run'
2020-09-22 03:11:12 default[20200921t205538]    /layers/google.ruby.bundle/gems/.bundle/gems/ruby/2.7.0/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/server.rb:327:in `start'
2020-09-22 03:11:12 default[20200921t205538]    /layers/google.ruby.bundle/gems/.bundle/gems/ruby/2.7.0/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/server.rb:168:in `start'
2020-09-22 03:11:12 default[20200921t205538]    /layers/google.ruby.bundle/gems/.bundle/gems/ruby/2.7.0/gems/rack-2.2.2/bin/rackup:5:in `<top (required)>'
2020-09-22 03:11:12 default[20200921t205538]    /workspace/.bundle/gems/ruby/2.7.0/bin/rackup:23:in `load'
2020-09-22 03:11:12 default[20200921t205538]    /workspace/.bundle/gems/ruby/2.7.0/bin/rackup:23:in `<top (required)>'
2020-09-22 03:11:13 default[20200921t205538]  nginx failed to start: aborted, context canceled. subject:"nginx" Timeout:30m0s, attempts:2
2020-09-22 03:11:13 default[20200921t205538]  "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500
```

Comment: Deployments to the standard environment are notably faster than deployments in flex. How fast is "too fast to be true"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error on the logs you provided states:

```
bundler: failed to load command: rackup (/workspace/.bundle/gems/ruby/2.7.0/bin/rackup)
```

I can see that you're using [Puma](https://puma.io/), and [the App Engine Standard docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/ruby/runtime#application_startup) specify some steps to take for apps that depend on [Rack](https://github.com/rack/rack):

> Most web applications use a Rack-supported web server such as Puma,
> Unicorn or Thin.
>
> You must add the server as a dependency in your application's `Gemfile`
> configuration file. The runtime will install all dependencies before
> your entrypoint is called.
>
> ```
> source "https://rubygems.org"
>
> gem "rack" 
> gem "puma"
> ```
>
> An example entrypoint using puma for a Rails application:
>
> ```
> entrypoint: bundle exec rails server Puma -p $PORT
> ```

The [instructions for flex](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/ruby/runtime#application_startup) are the same as the standard environment regarding the Gemfile and the entrypoint, so I'm not sure why one works and the other does not, but I encourage you to double-check if all those instructions are properly implemented.

I don't think there's anything inherently wrong with your `app.yaml`, since the API would reject the deployment if you passed a configuration that was not allowed in App Engine.

It is likely related to the entrypoint or the dependencies. This would allow building the container and deploying it, but would fail when the script actually tries to start.

Comment: This did the trick! Thank you so much. I added the 'rack' gem and changed my entrypoint from `entrypoint: bundle exec rails --port $PORT` to `entrypoint: bundle exec rails server Puma -p $PORT`

Answer (score 0):

From the description I believe that only `env: flex` to `env: standard` was changed, so  at least `runtime` should have to be changed as well.

If you take a look into documentation ([flex](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/ruby/runtime) and [standard](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/ruby/runtime)), the version of runtime is specified differently. In standard environment it is chosen by `runtime` value, while in flexible environment version is in:

> `.ruby-version` file in your application directory

There are of course others differences in `app.yaml` options available in both environments (references: [flex](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/ruby/reference/app-yaml) and [standard](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/ruby/config/appref)). So if you were able to deploy in flex you have to review all your setups.

Answer (score 0):

your app.yaml should have at least:

```
runtime: ruby25 # or ruby26 or ruby27 for Ruby 2.6 (beta) or Ruby 2.7 (beta)
entrypoint: bundle exec ruby app.rb
```

to deploy to app engine standard. do that then remove the older corrupted deployment. notice that no need to specify an `env`.

check [this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/ruby/quickstart) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Tried the above steps and unfortunately getting the same error. Even tried using ruby25 instead of ruby27. Is there a way to start over and deploy as if it's the first time? ```bundler: failed to load command: rackup (/workspace/.bundle/gems/ruby/2.5.0/bin/rackup)
2020-09-22 17:17:04 default[20200922t111230]  Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - tmp/pids/server.pid```